# Pass php array in onclick attribute of button and read it in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I am adding data to a table using ajax. In the onclick attribute of button I am calling a function which contains **id**, **name**, as first two parameters where as the **third parameter** is a **function call** which returns **array**.

Now the problem is that first two parameters are passed successfully to javascript function but third parameter which is array is not passing to javascript function.

How can I pass php array as a parameter to javascript function which can be accessed in javascript function like **array[0], array[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3GKA.png)** based on number of values in it. Please Help.

**PHP file:**

```
function allSizes($product_id)
{
    include("../../include/config.php");

    $allSizes = array();

    $products_extra_search = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT product_size from products_extra WHERE product_id = $product_id");
    while($products_extra_data = mysqli_fetch_array($products_extra_search))
    {
      $products_extra_size_id = $products_extra_data['product_size'];

      //getting size
      $product_size_search = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT size from products_size WHERE id = $products_extra_size_id");
      $products_size_data = mysqli_fetch_array($product_size_search);

      $allSizes[] = $products_size_data["size"];
    }

    return json_encode($allSizes);
}

    $output = '';

    $search = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * from products ORDER BY id DESC;");

    while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($search))
    {
        $output .= '<tr><td>                        
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" onclick="ProductExtraModal(`'.$data['id'].'`,`'.$data['name'].'`,`'.allSizes($data['id']).'`)"></a>
                    </td></tr>';
      }

    echo $output;
```

**Javascript Function that is called when button is clicked:**

```
function ProductExtraModal(id,name,size)
{ 
alert(id);
alert(name);
console.log(size); /*Not Working*/
}
```

**EDIT:**

After **HtmHell** answer output looks like

[image]

**Expected output:**

[image]

**Output of PHP array in browser:**

[image]

As i have six products with only first having two sizes. Can someone help please?

Comment: use `json_encode`

Comment: I have used it in PHP function

Comment: Use Escape quotes onclick="ProductExtraModal(\"'.$data['id'].'\",\"'.$data['name'].\"`,\"'.allSizes($data['id']).\"`)"

Comment: So you shouldn't use apostrophes beacuse it's not a string, it's an object. Like this: `(\''.$data['id'].'\',\''.$data['name'].'\','.allSizes($data['id']).')`

Comment: @HtmHell Its not working on every row. Giving errors on some rows

Comment: @Shaifu Look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass a json object so you shoudn't wrap it with any apostrophes.

Here is how it should be:

```
<?php
$output = '<tr><td>                        
        <a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" onclick="ProductExtraModal(`'.$data['id'].'`,`'.$data['name'].'`,'.allSizes($data['id']).')"></a>
    </td></tr>';
```

The problem is, json will contain `"` so it will break the HTML's attribute wrapper.

The final solution will be somethong like this:

```
<script>
// put this outside the loop
var allSizes = {};
</script>
<?php
    $output = '<tr><td>         
            <script>allSizes[' . $data['id'] . '] = ' . allSizes($data['id']) . ';</script>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" onclick="ProductExtraModal(`'.$data['id'].'`,`'.$data['name'].'`,allSizes[' . $data['id'] . '])"></a>
        </td></tr>';
```

Or escaping the apostrophes.

**Edit**

According to your comment, you have another issue: you are not getting the expected array.

I guess this happens beacuse in your `allSizes` function you aren't looping through `$product_size_search`, and you only call `mysqli_fetch_array` once.

Use this code instead, to loop throgh all product sizes:

```
function allSizes($product_id)
{
    include("../../include/config.php");

    $allSizes = array();
    $extraDataIds = array();

    $products_extra_search = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT product_size from products_extra WHERE product_id = $product_id");

    while ($products_extra_data = mysqli_fetch_array($products_extra_search)) {
        $extraDataIds[] = $products_extra_data['product_size'];
    }

    $product_size_search = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT size from products_size WHERE id IN (" . implode(",", $extraDataIds) . ") GROUP BY size");

    while ($products_size_data = mysqli_fetch_array($product_size_search)) {
        $allSizes[] = $products_size_data["size"];
    }

    return json_encode($allSizes);
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any error in the console / PHP error?

Comment: Its giving error on 
<script>var allSizes = allSizes($data['id']);</script>
so I removed ' ' from $data['id']

Comment: I updated the code, please put this inside the loop.

Comment: Its working now but array is containing only one element in the console

Comment: And how the HTML code (in the browswe, not in your code) looks like?
I want to see the part of `<script>var allSizes...`

Comment: I have updated question and HTML code contains only body tag of table as i am adding data to it by ajax

Comment: I dont think that there is a problem in allSizes function because PHP page is giving me the desired output

Comment: @Shaifu Updated my answer, you need to add `GROUP BY size` in the SQL query

Comment: see **Output of PHP array in browser** in my question. allSizes function does not have any problem i think

Comment: one thing that i want to mention is that <script>var allSizes = '.allSizes($data['id']).';</script> is executing twice I think that's why its returning only last element of array